# Is there exist a Holder $C^\alpha$ function $f$ such that for any continuous strictly increasing $g$, $f\circ g$ is not $C^{\alpha+}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

For any $\alpha>0$, can we find $C^\alpha$-function $f(x)$ that is "non-smooth" enough, such that for any continuous strictly increasing function $g(y)$, the function $f(g(y))$ is not $C^\beta$ for any $\beta>\alpha$.

In other words, there is no a topological parameterization such that $f$ cannot obtain a higher regularity under the new topological coordinate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f$ continuous and nowhere differentiable. Suppose that $f\circ g$ is differentiable for some continuous strictly increasing $g$. Then $g^{-1}$ is strictly monotonic too. Thus it is differentiable almost everywhere. But then $f=(f\circ g)\circ g^{-1}$ is differentiable almost everywhere. This is a contradiction.

*Remark:* The question has been changed *after* the answer! The original question was the following. *Is there exist a continuous function $f$ such that for any continuous strictly increasing $g$, $f∘g$ is not differentiable?*

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask that, does the idea of bound variation be generalized into consider the Holder regularity?